# My Joomla site is suddenly/inexplicably generating multiple errors

Tags: debugging, joomla

There are a series of new errors being generated by my Joomla website (url removed from this post by editor) and I haven't recently made any changes to prompt them:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: n2ace0b in /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 1
>
> Notice: Undefined index: n9e5e25 in /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/config.php on line 1
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/import.php:1) in /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 423
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/import.php:1) in /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 423
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/import.php:1) in /home/content/55/7579755/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line </code>
> ```

Why has this happened and how can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Have these errors occurred recently or have you been developing your site the whole time with them showing? Have you made any changes to the core Joomla code in any way? Have you tried disabling the most recent extensions you've installed?

Comment: No i never did any changes. these errors appears automatically.

Comment: If @Riccardo's answer is correct which is most likely is, I ask this question....what version of Joomla are you using (exact version, such as 2.5.23) and is it up to date?

Comment: From Apr 29, 2014, [joomla.se] Stack Exchange was born.  Please always post your Joomla questions there to reach a dedicated community that has an intimate knowledge of the CMS and extensions that are built upon it.

Answer (score 2):

Your site was hacked. And you're showing notices and warnings to the user.  You should take your site offline immediately and clean it.

Your database is compromised as well: There is plenty of spam inside the page (look for "buy inderal online no prescription")

But it seems they also managed to upload some php and mess up core files.

If you have a recent backup, that would be ideal. Otherwise a big cleanup is necessary.